# Добавление элементов в IList<>

Tags: c#, json, foreach

У меня есть класс

```
class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Так как я хочу прочитать и объединить объекты из разных файлов json создаю новый класс в котором объявляю поле

```
public static IList<Person> Persons = null;
```

И с помощью JsonConvert.DeserializeObject получаю все объекты Person с соответствующими атрибутами из каждого файла.

```
var persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Person>>(jsonFromFile);
```

Но когда через `foreach` добавляю в поле объекты, компилятор выдает что *"Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."* Но в тоже время проверил что объекты из json читаются и `persons` никогда не пустой.

```
foreach(Person person in persons)
{
    Persons.Add(person);
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста с вопросом. Не судите строго в C# я недавно. Могу попросту не знать всей логики построения классов или некоторого синтаксиса.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы пытаетесь десериализовать в интерфейс `IList<Person>`? Попробуйте `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonFromFile);` или `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person[]>(jsonFromFile);`

Comment: Да, везде `IList` поменяйте на `List`. И вместо `foreach` можно просто `Persons = persons`.

Comment: А чтобы склеить 2 списка, можно использовать [`AddRange`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.8). Это на случай, есди вы считываете данные в несколько итераций.

Comment: @tym32167, поменял на 'List' ошибка осталась прежней. Просто 'Persons = person' не могу сделать потому, что json файлы разные, и хотелось бы все объекты объединить в один массив.

Comment: Что то вы меня запутали. Причем тут `public static IList<Person> Persons`? Он не используется у вас в коде нигде. И приведите пример ваших json

Comment: А, ну и `public static IList<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();`

Comment: @tym32167, точно. Нужно было создать список вместо null. Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за `AddRange`!